# Easy PGP Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pgp

Is there easy use and install graphic pgp software for ubuntu 16.04?
Not for email use. 
I tried to install gnupg but instructions didn't work. 
Can I use email versions for text use only? What would be good?

Comment: You mean GPG ? https://gnupg.org/software/frontends.html

Comment: Yes. Should I try to get that installed or is there something better?

Comment: Still not working. How do I update gnupg2? Some command to update all?

Comment: Depends what are you trying to do ? simply stating it is not working or you want a graphical front end is insufficient. Post a command or see https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html  . Ubuntu uses seahorse https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse and kgpg https://utils.kde.org/projects/kgpg/

Comment: Installation did not complete, it said 10 "something" is unupdated or something. Propably that's why KGpg is not openin also. Something is missing and re-installation is not fixing that. I'm affraid Ubuntu is too much for me to handle. I don't need much else than browser but I would like to learn pgp use.

Comment: You need to post the commands you ran and error messages. GPG is failry broad, and it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: for a simple frontend try gpa

Answer (score 1):

The GUI for GnuPG is called "**seahorse**"

You can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install seahorse` at a command prompt.